# Performance issue in asp.net web api with identical action methods under same controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

So I have this very strange issue with asp.net web api.

Under the same controller I have two action methods, and one is being executed in matter of milliseconds and the other takes about 1.5 seconds to execute. The code inside both methods is identical.

I have never seen anything like this, and really don't know how to address this issue.

Here is my code

```
 [RoutePrefix("test/v420")]
    public class SomeController : ApiController
    {
        ISomeIndex someIndex;

        public Listings42_Controller(ISomeIndex someIndex)
        {
          someIndex = someIndex;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [RequireHttps]
        [Route("test1")]
        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetIndex()
        {
            var obj = await someIndex.Generate();

            return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                Content = new StringContent(SerializeToXml(obj),Encoding.UTF8, "application/xml")
            };
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [RequireHttps]
        [Route("test2")]
        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetIndex2()
        {
            var obj = await someIndex.Generate();

            return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                Content = new StringContent(SerializeToXml(obj),Encoding.UTF8, "application/xml")
            };
        }
}
```

**UPDATE**

So on dev server everything is working fine, on production server I have an issue with both methods when they are under SomeController. If I split methods into different controolers, then GetIndex() method under SomeController has poor performance and GetIndex2() under Some2Controller performs just fine.

Comment: Very strange. How're you calling the actions? Manually in a browser? Ajax calls? Postman?

Comment: I tried it all, and always the same outcome

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: I am just making a guess here. may be you  noticed performance issue from second action when first one was in progress and that Generate is blocking database or something. Did you start poorly performing action in parallel to first action or waited until it completed? just making some speculations here.